# Reorient Connectors of FK's in MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am having a quite "silly" problem with MySQLWorkbench. The thing is that in the diagram created from a Model, Foreign Keys are shown with dotted lines that connect one table o another. In each of the corresponding tables the beginning of the line is "pinned" to it, depending on the king of relationship (one-to-one, one-to-may, etc.) it displays different pins.

My problem is that I can't figure how to manually "unpin" the dotted line and "pin" it again in other part of the corresponding table. I want to do this for aesthetical reasons, because sometimes the way it pins makes it unable to appreciate the full dotted line, thus making the Diagram messy and hard to read.

Currently I am able to pan the dotted line, but it doesn't solve my problem and moving all the tables is not a viable solution also.

Here are some pics of what I am saying:
(Obstructed)

[image: View Obstructed by other Table]

(Panned but not OK)

[image: Panned way]

(What I would Like ... mad Paint skillz tho ;) )

[image: What I Want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulation of the relationships on a diagram is very limited at the moment. You can only move the center line in a three-part relationship. Everything else is determined based on different factors, like how many relations are attached to a table figure, what's the shortest way, the relative position etc.

Additionally, there are a few different relationship notations available. One is to connect straight lines to columns. But that's about it.